# How to use the argument of a Signal in QML StateMachine during SignalTransition

Tags: qt, qml, qt-signals

I have a C++ class and I made it possible to be able to create it in QML. Then I have a signal in QML which has an argument representing this object. I am using the `QtQml.StateMachine` and I am catching triggered signals with `SignalTransition`. I want to be able to set my signals argument to the next state when the `SignalTransition` triggers. In code:

This is how my signal looks like in Model.qml:

```
signal mySignal(CustomObject customObject)
```

My signal transitioning code in State.qml:

```
import QtQml.StateMachine 1.0 as SM

// SM.State { ...

Model {
    id: model
    // ...
}

SM.SignalTransition {
    targetState: nextState
    signal: model.mySignal
    onTriggered: console.log(customObject) // error here
}

// ... }
```

I get the following error: `ReferenceError: customObject is not defined`.
When I am emitting the signal I pass my customObject as an argument for the signal.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit of a hack, but the `guard` is passed the signal's parameters. The `guard` is an expression which is evaluated to see if it's true (and if so, the transition applies) but there's nothing stopping you running extra code in there. So:

```
State {
    targetState: nextState
    signal: model.mySignal
    guard: {
        // here, customObject is available, because it was an arg to the signal
        // so, stash it away somewhere where you can get at it later
        root.currentCustomObject = customObject;
        // and explicitly return true, so that this guard passes OK and
        // then the transition actually happens
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to have the `mySignal` handler set a property that can be summarily accessed by the less-flexible `SignalTransition`, like so:

```
Model {
    id: model
    property CustomObject currentObj
    onMySignal: currentObj = customObject
}

SM.SignalTransition {
    targetState: nextState
    signal: model.currentObjChanged
    onTriggered: console.log(model.currentObj)
}
```

Hacky and not tested, but might be acceptable for this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, this is how I am doing it right now and it works perfectly, but as you said it is a bit hacky and was wondering if there is a nicer solution. By this example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-statemachine-signaltransition.html#guard-prop it should some how work as I wrote it in my question, but I am still getting the error.

Comment: Right, then I don't know. I think for the code your question to work, the triggered signal would somehow carry arguments from the caller signal, which it apparantly does not?